# Close Scanner if no input

Tags: java, beginner, io

I'm in very early stages of learning some Java coding. I'm asking for this review because, although the code below works, I'd like to know if it's an ugly way of achieving it.
What I want the code to do is take input from Scanner and reprint it, except if the input is empty, ie, just hit the return key, in which case the Scanner should close and the program end.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Morse {

static boolean truefalse = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (truefalse)
{
String line = input.nextLine();
if (line.equals(""))
truefalse = false;
else
System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways your code can be improved:

1. Use nice indentation using 4 spaces. This improves the readability a lot. See the official guidelines on indentation [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#262).

   Basically every time you open a new curly brace you should start a new indentation depth. (See code sample below)
2. Use braces around all kinds of blocks, e.g. here even for one-lined `if/else` blocks. Also, for Java it is the [official convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449) to place the braces like this:

   ```
   if (line.equals("")) {
       truefalse = false;
   } else {
       System.out.println(line);
   }
   ```
3. You can use a trick to assign the value of the scanner input to a variable inside the while condition and then use the String's `isEmpty()` function to check if the input was empty. This way you can spare the `boolean` variable indicating whether something was read:

   ```
   while (!(line = input.nextLine()).isEmpty())
   ```
4. Use `try()` to create instances of `Types` that implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable` to make sure they are automatically closed when the block ends (Note this only works with Java 7 or newer):

   ```
   try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))
   ```

   See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for reference.

Putting that all together:

```
public class Morse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String line;
            while (!(line = input.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I realy dont know why noone uses `for`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/** The main program to read and write what the user inserts. */
public class Morse {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (String line = scanner.nextLine(); !line.isEmpty(); line = scanner.nextLine()) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Because

1. `close()` is called automatically on JVM end (see #7).
2. `truefalse` is in *default* scope. This is bad because noone should be able to have control about the inner work of the class in runtime - may match the Open-Close-Principle.
3. `truefalse` is a very bad variable name, `input` too. `line` is a good variable name.
4. Its ugly to have absolute no JavaDoc.
5. `for` has a variable-part, a condition-part and a increaser-part. Why dont shall we not use them?
6. `isEmpty()` is mutch better.
7. Close a `scanner` is a very very bad idea, even close indirectly using `try()`! You will never know when some one else replace the `System.in` by a Closeable-Stream, let the JVM decide when to close system streams!!!

Comment: Compare what you wrote to the [not while loop that @Nithathriel wrote](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70416/41243). "No one" uses the `for` loop because it's barely comprehend-able in comparison. Still you have some other valid points, so I refrain from voting one way or the other.

Comment: The `while` loop that @Nithrathriel have written makes a functioncall, a value-assignment and an empty-check in one single part. `for` uses 3 parts whear everyone knows the parts's responses. But this is not so important at all.

Comment: Another advantage of `for` is that it limits the scope of the loop variable `String line` to the loop. It's always good to limit variables to the smallest scope where they belong. +1

Comment: Thank you all for your input. It definitely seems like the thrust of my original question, ie, using a boolean, was a clumsy way of achieving what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

A petty little thing that the other answer didn't mention...

> ```
> // TODO Auto-generated method stub
> ```

Is this really still a Todo? Imagine yourself coming back to this code six months from now. Would you be *absolutely positive* that you completed the work here if you saw this? It's also important to note that most IDE's will pick up that `// TODO` comment in some kind of task list. This is just cluttering that up now. If you've implemented the code, remove the Todo.